# R why "==" operation doesn't return the same as %in%

Tags: r, vector, comparison

I have something strange when comparing two vectors:

```
individuals=c("A","C","X","Z")
m=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "X", "Z")
individuals == m
```

it return: TRUE FALSE ***FALSE*** FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE

At the end is for:

```
which(individuals == m)
```

which  return: 1 7 8

What I am missing?

Comment: What would be your expected outcome, perhaps you want `%in%`

Comment: sorry I should have precise, is for which(individuals == m) test. with %in% it's work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you get is indeed correct.
`R` compares each value pairwise:

```
individuals |   m   |  res
     A      |   A   |  T
     B      |   C   |  F
     C      |   X   |  F
     D      |   Z   |  F
```

it then recycle `m`:

```
individuals |   m   |  res
     E      |   A   |  F
     F      |   C   |  F
     X      |   X   |  T
     Z      |   Z   |  T
```

If you want to check if an element of `m` is in `individuals` use `%in%`:

```
m %in% individuals

# TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match`

```
!is.na(match(m, individuals))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The reason for the unexpected result is how the `==` compares the recycled elements i.e. the values in 'individuals' are replicated to the length of the 'm' vector

```
rep(individuals, length.out = length(m))
#[1] "A" "C" "X" "Z" "A" "C" "X" "Z"

m==rep(individuals, length.out = length(m))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: `m %in% individuals` maybe

Comment: @user20650  Thanks, but if found your comment so I left it in case you wanted to answer.  Also, somebody else posted

Comment: fair dos........although, from comment op ^^,  perhaps after all the answer is `match(individuals, m)`